# Setup Certificate Across Domain With IIS

Tags: ssl-certificate, microsoft-edge, chromium, iis-10, windows-server-2019

I have the following installed on the same physical windows server 2019

- Domain Controller (domain name XXX.local, hostname YYY)
- Certificate Authority
- IIS Server (with only default website)

I also have a couple of Linux webpage servers and Cisco router/switches

I'd like to use HTTPS but avoid the Not Secure Warning page, the following is what I've done.

1. I opened IIS Manager, under server certificates, Create Domain Certificate, filled in CN (Common Name) as YYY, Organization unit XXX.local
2. Right Click of the Default Website, Edit Bindings. Type https, Selected the SSL certificate just created. nothing else is filled.
3. View the certificate, copy to file, export it to shared folders, installed on client PC which belongs the the domain. Verified that the Trusted Root CA is listed correctly
4. Clear Cache and DNS record on client machine, restart website on server machine.

Yet I still get an error page stating that the Common Name is invalid.

What am I missing?
What do I need to do, to properly assign certificates to the rest of the webpages?

----------------update 2020-09-08---------------------

I've recreated a new certificate with YYY.XXX.local as the CN, same name as the friendly name of the CA. It worked for Internet Explorer
Yet it still doesn't work for Chrome and the new Edge (chromium core)
I tried to import the certificate, restart the browser but it refused to show up somehow.

Please note that through the whole time, the computer is within the same domain, thus, the Root CA certificate is installed. In fact, after I removed every 'manually imported' certificate, IE still works for me.

[Difference viewing certificates from mmc and from browser settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/olrHB.png)

Comment: https://docs.jexusmanager.com/tutorials/ssl-diagnostics.html Run a report and see what it says.

Comment: Report says certificate verified, no red word, it looked fine for me.
I've also changed the algorithm to SHA256 as I heard SHA1 is no longer supported, then revoked the old certificate, created a new one, applied it, same error.
The CN stated in the report under the line #subject: CN=YYY, OU=XXX.local, O=ZZZ
If it's not the CN mismatching the https://YYY/ in the browser, I wonder what error it could be.

Comment: You might then use openssl s_client to do client side testing, https://www.feistyduck.com/library/openssl-cookbook/online/ch-testing-with-openssl.html Its log should reveal more.

Comment: I'm sorry for my bad technique but I'm unable to complete such diagnose since I really don't know much about things around here.
However, I managed to create a new certificate with a proper CN and Friendly CA name this time, and the website worked with IE
But it doesn't work with Chrome and the new Edge which I'm currently using.
I tried to import the certificate, although completed, it just refuse to show up when viewing from the browser settings.

Comment: It is not bad technique, but you need to understand what is required by a browser to trust a server certificate. Export a .cer for that server certificate, and open that on the client machine you are testing on. Then the property dialog of Windows Explorer should show whether the chain works or not and you can troubleshoot from there ("Certificate path" tab in this screen https://i.stack.imgur.com/RsjCQ.png)

Comment: I made it working. See the newest question edit.

Comment: You should post that as an answer and accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made it working.

After some research, the certificate is missing SAN parameter within it. Chromium doesn't trust any certificate whose SAN is empty.

But directly request certificate from IIS manager doesn't have options to modify SAN parameter.

The solution, is to custom request certificate from local machine certificate manager, edit CN, SAN (typically DNS), etc. Then copy/paste the generated .req file content to http://localhost/certsrv/ Download and install the approved certificate, then bind it back to website on IIS manager.